# R: control auto-created column names in call to rbind()

Tags: r

If I do something like this:

```
> df <- data.frame()
> rbind(df, c("A","B","C"))
  X.A. X.B. X.C.
1    A    B    C
```

You can see the row gets added to the empty data frame.  However, the columns get named automatically based on the content of the data.

This causes problems if I later want to:

```
> df <- rbind(df, c("P", "D", "Q"))
```

Is there a way to control the names of the columns that get automatically created by rbind?  Or some other way to do what I'm attempting to do here?

Comment: Why can't you just rename the columns before running the next rbind?  `colnames(df) <- c("one","two","three")`

Comment: This may have more to do with the implicit conversion of these strings to factors, see @baha-kev's answer below.

Comment: Answering your question below.  `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` will fix the conversion to factors.  And, no, there is no "need" to use factors while doing this `rbind`.  once the `stringsAsFactors` option is set, your current `rbind` steps should work just fine.  however, one could probably make the case for a different method of constructing your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@baha-kev has a good answer regarding strings and factors.

I just want to point out the weird behavior of `rbind` for data.frame:

```
# This is "should work", but it doesn't:
# Create an empty data.frame with the correct names and types
df <- data.frame(A=numeric(), B=character(), C=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rbind(df, list(42, 'foo', 'bar')) # Messes up names!
rbind(df, list(A=42, B='foo', C='bar')) # OK...

# If you have at least one row, names are kept...
df <- data.frame(A=0, B="", C="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rbind(df, list(42, 'foo', 'bar')) # Names work now...
```

But if you only have strings then why not use a matrix instead? Then it works fine to start with an empty matrix:

```
# Create a 0x3 matrix:
m <- matrix('', 0, 3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3]))

# Now add a row:
m <- rbind(m, c('foo','bar','baz')) # This works fine!
m

# Then optionally turn it into a data.frame at the end...
as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the option "stringsAsFactors" to False, which stores the values as characters:

```
df=data.frame(first = 'A', second = 'B', third = 'C', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rbind(df,c('Horse','Dog','Cat'))
  first second third
1     A      B     C
2 Horse    Dog   Cat

sapply(df2,class)
      first      second       third 
"character" "character" "character"
```

Later, if you want to use factors, you could convert it like this:

```
df2 = as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors=T)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I implied that all my data would be letters.  They are not,  they are arbitrary strings.  This does help.  I guess another way to skin this cat would be to prevent them from turning into factors, can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to keep your data as factors, if you want to use a data.frame object.  I've edited the code in my answer to accept any arbitrary string.

Comment: Can you explain briefly why "you need to keep your data as factors"?  Thanks for your patience, I'm a newb.

Comment: Actually, you don't!  I've edited my response -- you can store your values as characters.  I learn something new every day!